# Auto insert await when asyncio function in hy-lang

Tags: macros, hy

The following `do/a` macro can auto-insert `await` when `asyncio` function is used.
The following also shows usage.

```lisp
(import asyncio)
(import time)

(defmacro do/a [&rest code] 
  `(do ~@(lfor p code
                (if
                  (= (cut (str (first p)) -2) "/a")
                  `(await ~p)
                  p))))

(defmacro progn/a [&rest code]
  `(.run_until_complete (.get-event-loop asyncio )
     ((fn/a []
        (do/a ~@code)
        ))
     ))

(defn/a sleep_test/a [t]  
  (await (asyncio.sleep t))
  (print t)
  t)

(defn sleep_test [t]  
  (time.sleep t)
  (print t)
  t)

(progn/a
  (print 3)
  (await (sleep_test/a 3))
  (sleep_test/a 2) ;;can omit await
  (sleep_test 1) ;;auto swich by fn name 
  (+ 20 30)
  )
```

This macro detects async function by the function name "/a".
It is better using  `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction` to detect  async functions.
But this does not work.
Plz see the following macro and executed result.

```lisp
(defmacro isasynctestmac [f]
  (if (asyncio.iscoroutinefunction f)
      `["async"  ~(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction f) (asyncio.iscoroutinefunction ~f) (type ~f)] 
      `["not async" ~(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction f) (asyncio.iscoroutinefunction ~f) (type ~f)] 
          ))

(isasynctestmac sleep_test/a)

==> ['not async', False, True, <class 'function'>]
```

You will see an async function is regarded as a symbol in hy-lang macro.
Appling `eval` can not avoid this problem.

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Macros run at compile time, and whether a variable holds a coroutine is only known at run time, so `iscoroutinefunction` needs to be called at run time. `(asyncio.iscoroutinefunction f)` in your macro `isasynctestmac` merely checks the symbol that's used as the variable name, not the value of the variable. Here's how you could write `do/a` with `iscoroutinefunction`, and here's the rest of the code with e.g. the extra parenthesis in `sleep_test` removed. (In the future, make sure the parts of your code that are supposed to already work really do already work before posting to Stack Overflow.)

```
(import asyncio time) 

(defmacro do/a [&rest code] 
  `(do ~@(lfor p code
    (if (and (instance? HyExpression p) p (!= (first p) (HySymbol "await")))
      `(if (asyncio.iscoroutinefunction ~(first p))
        (await ~p)
        ~p)
      p))))

(defmacro progn/a [&rest code]
  `(.run_until_complete (.get-event-loop asyncio)
    ((fn/a []
      (do/a ~@code)))))

(defn/a sleep_test/a [t]  
  (await (asyncio.sleep t))
  (print t)
  t)

(defn sleep_test [t]  
  (time.sleep t)
  (print t)
  t)

(print (progn/a
  (print 3)
  (await (sleep_test/a 3))
  (sleep_test/a 2)
  (sleep_test 1)
  (+ 20 30)))
```

Comment: This approach causes error when write await in non-async code. `(defn sleep_test [t hintfn] (if (asyncio.iscoroutinefunction hintfn)
      (await (asyncio.sleep t))
      (time.sleep t))`  =>  `hy.lex.exceptions.PrematureEndOfInput: Premature end of input` . Then I use function name for distinguishing async context in my lib https://pypi.org/project/gasync/

Comment: @niitsuma `PrematureEndOfInput` is a syntax error. It's telling you that you forgot a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The approach   @Kodiologist show has the following problem.
The following python code works.

```py
import asyncio
import time
async def sleep_testa(t, hintfn):
    await asyncio.sleep(t) if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(hintfn) else time.sleep(t)
```

But after remove `async` before `def`, the program stop with error
 `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```py
import asyncio
import time
def sleep_testa(t, hintfn):
    await asyncio.sleep(t) if asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(hintfn) else time.sleep(t)
==> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems to impossible dynamically switching async and non-async code. 
We must switch async and non-async code before macro expand.